# Does FactoryGirl class definition directly call the Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm a noob at factory girl.
Does the below code actually instantiate the model Contact I created in app/models/Contact?
So when I call the method I get an instance of the actual model class I created?
Is there any more clear way of naming it?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :contact do |f|
        f.firstname { Faker::Name.first_name }
        f.lastname { Faker::Name.last_name }
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.  You can confirm this with:

```
contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)
puts contact.class #=> Contact
```